# TO find out any user using SQL on specific table

Tags: sql

I'm working as an user. I want to know if the other user making any INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on any specific table. How to find out ? is there any SQL to do so ?

Comment: If you had access to see queries being run, you'd only know after the fact.  SQL itself doesn't cover this.

Comment: lock the table down and then see who complains!  ;)

Comment: Without stored procedures, no.

Comment: Hmm, seems we have limitation in SQL. Just checking an operation on table shouldn't be a problem for any user (the one who is working and other one who is just auditing).

Comment: What database product? Some have auditing features.

Answer (score 0):

Make a trigger on the table and write the username into a log table.

In oracle you'd get the user from sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER');

Other db's have similar functionality.